# Combine two triangular meshes

Tags: merge, mesh, triangulation

I have two triangular meshes over a given 2-D domain. The goal is to combine these meshes and create a third triangular mesh such that it contains all edge and node information of the initial meshes. The following image is a pictorial presentation of what I am looking for:

[image]

I am looking for a Matlab code to do this. I have searched a lot, but what I have found seems to be different.

Answer (score 0):

This function does exactly what I want:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48613-surface-intersection?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com